# Duplicate image when using AsyncImageView

Tags: iphone

I have used AsyncImageView lib to load image on iCarousel. It duplicated images when load finish an image from URL . Anybody has this problem?

Any solution for this?

EDITED: I have found solution!

Because I used Paging type so it just load 1 item at a time. So it retain the previous imageview,
what I should do is reset image in this ImageView by
imageview.image = nil;

before load another item.

Comment: No i am not getting any issue in AsyncImageView. Can you show your code?

Comment: It just like in the example. I have a Array of image URL from service 
here my code ` if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:iCarousel_Dock.bounds] autorelease];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    }
    [[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingImagesForTarget:view];

    //set image URL. AsyncImageView class will then dynamically load the image
    NSURL *url_Docks = [NSURL URLWithString:[listImagesDock objectAtIndex:index]];
    ((AsyncImageView *)view).imageURL = url_Docks;
    return view;
`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try `AsyncImageView` before, I am not sure if that is a problem in the library itself or in the way you use it.

But I use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) and it doesn't cause the duplication problem, I recommend to give it a try :)